# J2ME Canvas fill background in for loop

Tags: java-me

Im developing a small app with J2ME Midlet and i know canvas is very strong in low level to create GUI. I try some code to create GUI but i got stuck when i try to fill and draw it!

I dont know how can i draw it in loop look like this picture below:

I wanna fill background like this picture gray and black in loop

http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2011/028/2/1/music_player_tutorial_by_app_juice-d388pcq.jpg

I mean if i have a vector or a int variable

```
int value = 10

for(int i = 0; i< value; i++){
      if(i % 2 ==0){
         Fill gray
      }else{
         Fill black
      }
   what should i do in this loop?
}
```

i dont know how to identify coordinate X and Y  when use for loop

i need expert help me

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

[You can use this](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Draw_Gradient_in_Java_ME), or at least you can check how he did it.

Comment: Thank you!!  But i wanna know how to do it in loop because i cant identify X and Y coordinate  :)